# How do you make composite primary key with one being autogenerated?

Tags: android-room, composite-primary-key

I have the following object:

```
@Entity(tableName = "Section", primaryKeys = ["sectionID","number","numberOfServers"])
data class Section(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "number")
    var number: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "numberOfServer")
    var numberOfServers: Int
){
    @ColumnInfo(name = "sectionID")
    var id: Long = 0
}
```

then I have the DAO method to insert into room as such:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
suspend fun insertSection(section: Section): Long
```

My goal is for an insert operation to be ignored if a Section object with the same pair of number and numberOfServers already exists in the database. In addition I want the section to have an id which is autogenerated by room. I have seen posts that use indexes and the unique attribute to achieve the composite primary key part of my goal and then use the @PrimaryKey(autogenerate = true) to generate the id. However I am not sure that using indexes works the same as primaryKeys does. As far as I see it if I use indexes and set those to unique room will check

```
if(index1 != unique){  
   ignore
}else if(index2 != unique){
  ignore
...
etc.
```

while what I want is more of a

```
   if((index1 && index2 combination) != unique){
      ignore
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that indexes do offer the functionality I need according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data) and so I ended up with this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "Section", indices = [Index(value = ["number","numberOfServer"], unique = true)])
data class Section(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "number")
    var number: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "numberOfServer")
    var numberOfServers: Int
){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "sectionID")
    var id: Long = 0
}
```

Thank you for participating